# Get GitHub repository URL from commit

Tags: python, git, github

I would like to get a GitHub Repository URL from a Commit HASH.

I quickly found this solution:

```
import json
import requests

def search_commits(sha):
   headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'}
   req = requests.get('http://api.github.com/search/commits',
       {'q': sha},
       headers=headers)
   return json.loads(req.text)


commit = search_commits('e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290')['items'][0]
clone_url = commit['repository']['url']
```

The I tried the same with `PyGitHub`:

```
from github import Github
g = Github()

commit = g.search_commits('e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290')[0]
```

Unfortunately in this result (even in `commit.raw_data`) there is no key `repository`.

It seems PyGitHub uses `search/commits` as described here: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits

How can I get the URL of the repository?

One possible kludge would be:

```
import re

repo = g.get_repo(
    re.search('repos/(.*?)/commits', c.raw_data['url']).group(1)
)
clone_url = repo.clone_url
```

Comment: Commits don't know their URLs as they can be pushed to many remotes. What info do you want to get with the URL?

Comment: @phd, How can you explain I am able to retrieve the repository from the commit object then (see the kludge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is available in `_rawData`, but I doubt it's intended usage, prefixing an underscore is usually done to signify a private attribute

```py
from github import Github
g = Github()

commit = g.search_commits('e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290')[0]
url = commit._rawData['repository']['url']

print(url)
```